# Is it possible to determine coefficients of an analog Bessel filter based on order, fc and attenuation only?

Tags: filter, signal, signal-processing

In our work, we were given a data which according to documentation has been filtered via an 'analog four pole low pass Bessel filter at 2kHz with attenuation of signals above -3dB of 80dB/decade'. We are now tasked with creating a model of the original system (and therefore a model of filter too), but can receive no further information, and circuit diagrams are unavailable. Is it possible to obtain the filter coefficients based on such limited info?

I am trying to study the filters theory for past two days, and while I feel like I understand the basics, I am genuinely stuck. Would also welcome any resources pertaining to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to obtain the filter coefficients based on such limited info?

In principle yes.

- it is a Low-pass filter
- it has a cut-off frequency of 2 kHz
- roll-off is 80 dB/decade so that means it is a (4 x 20 dB/decade) 4th order filter
- since no input and output impedance are given, I will assume both are 50 ohms

The "oldfashioned" way to design such a filter was to lookup the coefficients in a book like [Zverev](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471749427), do some "magic" with those numbers and you'd have your filter design.

Luckily there are easier methods these days. I prefer to use [QUCS](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/) (it is free software!) which is a circuit simulator (so you can immediately simulate your filter!) but it has a built-in **filter generator** which I use quite often.

So I filled in the above specifications and then I get:

[image]

As stated, this filter **requires** the 50 ohm input and output impedances. If you want something different and since you're making a **model** it is quite easy to use controlled sources (voltage to voltage, current to voltage, etc) to make the impedances as seen from "outside" as you need them without affecting the filter.

For example, if you **replace** P1 a voltage to voltage source in series with 50 ohms, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuRU68.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then you get a high impedance input but the filter still sees a 50 ohm source (which it needs).

Comment: How about the linear phase requirement?

Comment: @ScottSeidman As this is a Bessel type filter, it should have the linear phase behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A [Besel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter) filter is built, normally, for its flat group delay, which ensures very little overshoot in time domain. It's not impossible to see these filters built for a certain corner frequency, though their frequency domain is rather poor.

However, as seen in the link above, a prototype 4th order Bessel will have this transfer function:

$$H(s)=\frac{105}{s^4+10s^3+45s^2+105s+105}$$

which gives an attenuation of ~0.63dB@1Hz. To find out the location of the frequency for the -3dB point, you need to use numerical methods, or simulators:

[image: fc]

The readings show that fc=2.114Hz, so if you want -3dB@1Hz you need to normalize the filter to this value (ω/2.114). Whether it's needed, or not, it's up to the requirements of your problem.

Whatever the choice, what you need to do is take the above prototype filter and divide `s` to the new value for ω (pulsation, not frequency), and you'll have your 4th transfer function.

To actually build the filter you'll need to separate the result into two 2nd order sections (mostly for stability), and for this you'll need to find out the roots of the denominator. Using your favourite program, you'll find out that the roots are these:

```
  -2.1038 + 2.6574i
  -2.1038 - 2.6574i
  -2.8962 + 0.8672i
  -2.8962 - 0.8672i
```

Note that these are normalized values, the scaling is up to you. With these you can build two 2nd order denominators. From then on, it's as simple as implementing the two filters with your favourite topology (Sallen-Key, multiple-feedback, etc), though Sallen-Key would be much preferred here for it's simplicity and low Q requirements of the Bessel poles. I am leaving this task up to you, I wouldn't want to deprive you of your joys.